# How do I hardcode a skipped test using Boost.Test?

Tags: c++, testing, boost

While coding using python's unittest module, I have found it useful to mark tests to be skipped on execution (see [unittest.SkipTest exception in python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html))

Is there anything similar in Boost.Test?

I am implementing my tests using boost version 1.49.0 and I want to add something like:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_wibly)
{
    throw boost::???::skip_test("http://my::defect.tracking.software/#4321");
}
```

Basically this should not consider the test as passed or failed, but "skipped" and it should appear so in the output.

If there is nothing like it, where can I find some resources on how to implement it myself (on top of Boost.Test)?

The documentation has a section on skipping tests, but it refers to skipping a test suite if a previous test fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this with Boost Test.

I have run across the [NCBI C++ Toolkit](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7200/), which has an enhanced version of Boost Test that adds these sort of capabilities. I haven't had an occasion to try it yet, so I can't vouch for it.

Comment: Then I guess I'll have to look into doing something myself. I will probably look into how NCBI C++ Tk does it. Thanks.